# Не могу зациклить скрипт в Javascript

Tags: javascript, циклы

Не могу добиться зацикливания. То есть, чтобы после клика по 3ему изображению, открывалось 1ое и цикл повторялся бесконечно.

Заранее спасибо!

```js
var i = 0;
var imgs = new Array('001A.jpg', '002A.jpg', '003A.jpg');

function imgsrc() {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  image.src = imgs[++i];
  console.log(image.src);
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="001A.jpg" onClick="imgsrc();">
```

Comment: остаток от деления нацело вам в помощь. Как и передача this как аргумента функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
image.src = imgs[i = ++i % 3];
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
if (++i === imgs.length) i = 0
image.src = imgs[i]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
image.src = imgs[++i];
if (i == imgs.length - 1)
  i = -1;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @pomogite Пожалуйста. Успехов! Примите один из ответов - "галочка" слева.

Comment: Зачем удалил ответ?

Comment: @Qwertiy Подумал, что он не добавляет полезного к другим двум.